# Extending dictionary with cascading methods

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, super, self

I am extending the dict class in python:

```
import jmespath
import json

class superDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def prettyPrint(self):
        print(self.pprettyPrint())
    
    def pprettyPrint(self):
        return json.dumps(self, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    
    def search(self, pattern):
        return jmespath.search(pattern, self)
    
   ...
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
regDict = {"key": "value"}
super = superDict(regDict)
super.search('patern').prettyPrint()
```

the problem I have here is that jmespath can return a list, so I cannot do:

```
    def search(self, pattern):
        return superDict(jmespath.search(pattern, self))
```

Next idea would be creating a prettyprint class that superDict would inherit from and could also be used in the return of search:

```
class superDict(dict, prettyprint):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...

    def search(self, pattern):
        return prettyprint(jmespath.search(pattern, self))

class prettyprint: ???
```

But I can't figure out what the prettyprint class would look like for this to work. I basically can't think of an elegant way to do this. Maybe some logic in **init** around the arg type would be simpler?

Comment: no matter what jmespath returns, prettyprint should just json.dump. But my wrapper expect a dictionary, so superDict([list]) errors out.

Comment: Pprint is not really the problem. I am more interested in a elegant way to cascade a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **new**

```
class extensions:
    def prettyPrint(self):
        print(self.pprettyPrint())
        return self
    
    def pprettyPrint(self):
        return json.dumps(self, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    
    def search(self, pattern):
        return exJSON(jmespath.search(pattern, self))

class exList(list, extensions):
    def prettyTable(self, headers):
        x = PrettyTable()
        x.field_names = headers
        for row in self:
            x.add_row(row.values())
        x.align = "l"
        print(x)
        return self

class exDict(dict, extensions):
    pass
        
class exStr(str, extensions):
    pass

class exJSON:
    def __new__(self, obj):
        if type(obj) is dict:
            return exDict(obj)
        if type(obj) is list:
            return exList(obj)
        if type(obj) is str:
            return exStr(obj)
        else:
            return obj
```